# android studio not working because of upgrading new one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, upgrade

My android studio was working properly but recently demanded to upgrade and I accepted.

Since then, all thing destroyed and gradle error is what I encounter.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-7.1.3.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.3/gradle-7.1.3.jar
> Could not find builder-7.1.3.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.3).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.3/builder-7.1.3.jar

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

I'm totally confused. Whatever I did, it could not be solved.
thanks before for help

```html
this is setting.gradle()



pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

```html
this is app/build.gradle



plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

```html
and this is build.gradle(:)


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you could be missing proper repository declarations.
Try adding `google()` and `mavenCentral()` to your top level build.gradle and retry gradle sync.

If problem is not solved, please add stacktrace or errors you encounter so we can help you.

Comment: plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: that is all of my build.gradle(:)

Comment: i think you've send your app-level build.gradle, could you send your project-level one ? also add it as snippet to your question so people could easily understand the problem for later use, thanks

Comment: In the build.gradle(:) I changed version 7.1.3 to 7.1.0 suddenly and apparently the problem solved. Does anyone know why and if it will be changed to other version how?